# Bootstrap html width = 1903x1128, want 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want my webpage to work on mobile, as well as desktop, so I am using bootstrap. I have body, `.container-fluid`, and even tried setting html to `width: 100%`. But it doesn't fill the entire width. How can I make the whole page float the entire width?

I can't attach an image, but using the inspector tool, the html element has size 1903x1128 with no margin or padding.

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0%;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    font-size: 25pt;
    padding: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Can you give link to the site?

Comment: I could, except I just deleted all my previous code to start the layout from scratch.

Comment: Post your html & css then..

Comment: Are you loading bootstrap css after your custom css? Or there is other CSS overriding what you've posted here.

Comment: Chad W you're on to something........